# \setcounter{section} problems with TOC hyperref links

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In writing my thesis, I have two Parts each of them composed by several Chapters. I use \input to include the different Chapters files. At the beginning of each Part I want to write an introductory section, and I want it to appear in TOC as Section i.1 and Section i.2.
Now the naming and the page numbering works fine. However, hyperref link from TOC points to the previous Section with the same number.
It is more clear with this MWE:

The main file is

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12 pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\mainmatter
\input{File1}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

%%%%-----------------------%

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Title Part 1}
\input{File2}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

File 1 is

```
\section{First section}
\lipsum

\section{Second section}
\lipsum
```

File 2 is

```
\thispagestyle{empty} \phantom{}

\vfill
\begin{center}
{\huge \scshape\bfseries Title Part I\\}
\end{center}
\vfill
\newpage

{\clearpage\phantomsection\renewcommand\thechapter{\rm S}
\setcounter{section}{0} 
\label{sec:intro1}
\section{Section S1}
\lipsum}

% In the real file I have here many others Chapters and Sections.

{\clearpage\phantomsection\renewcommand\thechapter{\rm S}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Section S2}
\label{sec:intro2}
\lipsum}
```

When now I compile, the clickable link of Section i1 points to First Section and Section i2 points to Second Section.
How to have the links pointing to the right place?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The size option is called `12pt`; the fact that also `12 pt` works in incidental. You can avoid the clumsy `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage` by just loading `emptypage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd define an environment in order to avoid too much repetitive code in the document body. The main trick is to save the value of the “part sections” and to locally redefine `\theHsection` so as to not confuse `hyperref` with double references to the same object.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcounter{partsection}

\newenvironment{Part}[1]
 {%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \setcounter{section}{\value{partsection}}%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}%
  \renewcommand{\theHsection}{S\arabic{section}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{center}
  \huge\scshape #1
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \clearpage
 }
 {%
  \setcounter{partsection}{\value{section}}%
  \cleardoublepage
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}
\lipsum

\section{Second section}
\lipsum

\begin{Part}{Title Part I}

\section{Section i1}
\label{sec:intro1}
\lipsum

\section{Section i2}
\label{sec:intro2}
\lipsum
\end{Part}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\section{First section}
\lipsum

\section{Second section}
\lipsum


\begin{Part}{Title Part II}

\section{Section i1}
\label{sec:intro3}
\lipsum

\section{Section i2}
\label{sec:intro4}
\lipsum
\end{Part}

\chapter{Third chapter}

\section{First section}
\lipsum

\section{Second section}
\lipsum

\ref{sec:intro1} \ref{sec:intro2}
\ref{sec:intro3} \ref{sec:intro4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea of defining a new environment. Like this the code is surely more clean. However it does not solve my problem. The {\rm i} command for the section after the beginning of each part did not mean to stand for \roman. I changed it with {\rm S} in the main question. As you can see now, what I would like to have is that {\rm S} labels all initial sections independently from the Part. The first section of the first Part would be S.1, the first section of the second Part S.2, and so on.

Comment: @Tommaso I don't understand: how should the second section of the first part be numbered?

Comment: This should be the structure:
1. First Chapter
1.1 First Section --

Title Part I - 
S.1 Section S1 -
S.2 Section S2 --

2 Second Chapter -
2.1 First section -
2.2 Second section ---

Title Part II -
S.3 Section S3 -
S.4 Section S4 --

3 Third Chapter -
3.1 First section -
3.2 Second section

Comment: @Tommaso This should now be what you like.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly! I did not know about \newcounter{partsection}. This is the key command which makes it working. Thanks!